# Rails 4 solr sunspot in production environment schema.xml isn't being read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am running a rails production app on an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment and have setup the sunspot gem. Until now it has been working properly, I run it via the rake sunspot:solr:start command and reindex each time I deploy and searching works as intended.

Today, I needed to modify the schema.xml file in order to add an ASCIIFoldingFilter for querying and indexing. I added the filter and tested it in my local development environment and it worked.

However when I did the same in production (on my EBS environment), even though the SOLR admin panel showed that the schema file was modified properly, the filter did not work. I checked the "Analysis" tab from my production core and confirmed that the filter wasn't being used.

I am at a total loss as to why my filters aren't taking effect. I tried stopping/starting SOLR, reindexing and so forth and nothing seems to work.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you reindex the entire data set? rake sunspot:reindex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when I did rake sunspot:solr:stop it was trying to stop a non-existing PID. After I killed the Solr process with kill -9 and restarted it, the schema.xml file was read properly.